# bash double quote inside a double quote

Tags: bash

trying to make this work

```
selected="key"
echo "ls -1rt log/* | tail -n3" |while read i; do grep \"$selected\" \"$i\" -B 50 -A 50; done"
```

Say I have a directory named log which contains a few files. I want to search text in the most three recent updated files. I have tried multiple ways but $i is always null.

Comment: Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You clarify in a comment that you are actually using `ssh` and not `echo`.

I shall assume that the double-quote after `-n3` is a typo.

The issue is that you are not escaping the `$` in `$i`. So it is expanded by the local shell as the string is read, not by the remote shell when the command is executed.

Replace with `\$i` and the command should work properly.

You can use the output of echo to check that the command has been escaped correctly. Running it on your sample (with `-n3"` corrected to `-n3`) would show `""` in the output instead of `"$i"` deomonstrating that the variable was expanded too soon.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. echo is semantically meaningless here but I use echo as my actual command is 'ssh root@$f "ls -1rt log/* | tail -n3 |while read i; do grep "('$Consulate', '$selected')" "$i" -B 50 -A 50; done";'. Using echo and set -x allows me to see the actual command.